# libpgiod vs wiringPI ports/pins etc

Tags: gpio, libgpiod

since sysfs is deprecated, and wiringPi can't really be used anymore, I started with libgpiod.

I found some examples I am trying to play with. But nothing yet. (I am trying to get an libpgiod version of blink working).

I was wondering,  in libgpio are the pin numbers the same as on the  RI boards/pin-headers?

and, more than likely,  did anyone build a libgpiod equivalent of the blink example (from wiringPi for example)?

thanks,

Ron

(no real good tags below, because it won't let me add/use any).

Comment: Added libgpiod As a tag for you.

Comment: pigpio uses Broadcom numbering. https://pinout.xyz/

Answer (score 1):

libgpiod (the replacement for sysfs for GPIO) uses Broadcom GPIO numbering.

I.e. libgpiod GPIO x is Broadcom GPIO x.

Broadcom numbering is indicated with BCM in the following.

https://pinout.xyz/

Comment: Ahhh...  that was what I was acually wondering.  That helps!!  thanks!!

Comment: ok,  that actually worked!!   cool.   (of course I already had the pinout link you showed.)